# Deploying Django + Next JS

Tags: django, deployment, next.js

I have built Django + Next JS website and now I want to deploy. I don't know which one to prefer hosting server or VPS. Website is simple, static and kind of catalogue. Next JS default homepage is pages/index.js. I mean it is not index.html, it is index.js

1. Is it possible on hosting server? I'm asking because next js is also need to run node js server on development.
2. On VPS plan does anyone know about how to dockerize exactly this things?
3. Hosting or VPS?
4. Which hosting server do you prefer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on you preferences and how you plan on developing the app further and maintaining it.

Some providers do give an option to configure your instances as you wish, others don't.

You could consider using
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

if your app has only client part and if you don't use server side render

Personally I would recommend to consider either Heroku, Digital Ocean or AWS for your deployments but it highly depends on your cost expectations etc.

All of these give you an option to configure you're server instances as you wish.

`Heroku` might need a bit less configuration, but probably is less flexible at the same time.

`Digital Ocean` or `AWS` will give you full control over the instances but will take a bit more effort for setting up the deployment etc.